# How to Run python on visual studio code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

i am trying to run python on vs code. i installed python(microsoft) from the extention,coderrunner. yet everytime i run a code,it shows, "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store"
how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you edit your Question and paste the output from VS Code?

Comment: Download the exe from python.org

Comment: Also check https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-windows

Answer (score 1):

You don't have python installed on your system or its not added to your PATH.
Install it with the microsoft store or going to [python.org](https://python.org) and downloading your version on choice. Don't forget to select the *"ADD TO PATH"* option in the installer.

Comment: in which path should i add it?

Comment: What do you mean? Like the installation directory, that you should just leave as is. For the rest there isnt anything you need todo.

Comment: well, i have installed python from python.org already & also installed python by microsoft from vs code extension...

Comment: Has the problem been solved now?